# Работа со стеком

Tags: c++

Есть структура стек

```
struct Stack {
            int inf;         // значение элемента
            Stack *next;    // указатель на следующий эле-мент 
} *begin;            // Указатель вершины стека
```

Как удалить элементы, находящиеся между максимальным и минимальным значением?

Comment: а что делать, если минимальных и максимальных значений много? например, если все значения равны?

Comment: @VladD, этот вариант не рассматривается.....в стеке нет повторяющихся элементов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в стеке нет повторяющихся элементов, делайте так:

1. Заведите новый временный стек
2. Перекладывайте элементы из данного стека во временный по одному. Запоминайте текущее минимальное и максимальное значение, а также их номера.
3. Вычислите минимум и максимум из индексов минимального и максимального элементов.
4. Затем переложите значения из временного стека назад в данный, пропуская значения между минимальным и максимальным индексами.

---

Псевдокод:

```
Stack<T> temp;
if (s.Empty())
    return;
T val = s.Pop();
int minidx = 0, maxidx = 0;
T minval = val, maxval = val;
temp.Push(val);

int curridx = 1;
while (!s.Empty())
{
    T val = s.Pop();
    if (val < minval)
    {
        minval = val;
        minidx = curridx;
    }
    if (val > maxval)
    {
        maxval = val;
        maxidx = curridx;
    }
    temp.Push(val);
    curridx++;
}

int startidx = max(minidx, maxidx);
int endidx = min(minidx, maxidx);

while (!temp.Empty())
{
    curridx--;
    T val = temp.Pop();
    if (curridx >= startidx || curridx <= endidx)
        s.Push(val);
}
```

Comment: что под номерами имеется ввиду?

Comment: индексы. на каждом перекладывании увеличивайте счётчик на единицу.

Comment: @VladD, а часть кода можно....не могу понять ..Перекладывайте элементы из данного стека во временный по одному. Запоминайте текущее минимальное и максимальное значение, а также их номера...Вычислите минимум и максимум из индексов минимального и максимального элементов.

Comment: Вот вам код :)

`minval`, `maxval` — текущее мин. и макс. значение, `minidx` и `maxidx` — их индексы (номера).

Comment: @VladD запоминание индексов -- операция лишняя (поскольку значения уникальны). Но. Есть шанс, что задача -- учебная и выдана (составлена) достаточно неграмотным преподавателем, который не знает, что возможности работать со стеком, как со списком/массивом может и не быть.

Comment: @alexlz: вы правы, но всё равно придётся выяснять, какое из значений "первое", а какое "второе". С индексами эта логика прозрачнее. (Иначе при переборе назад придётся сравнивать значение с обоими, запоминать состояние, и обрабатывать отдельно случай одного элемента в стеке).

---
Задача явно учебная, т. к. стек не предназначен для операций такого типа. Мой код работает со стеком честно, только push/pop/empty.

Comment: @VladD Что значит "первое" и "второе"? Обнаружено одно при возврате в оригинальный стек -- прекращаем push, после второго -- возобновляем. А вот за честное решение студент может получить снижение оценки, если преподаватель упёртый.

Comment: @alexlz: вам придётся писать что-то наподобие такого:

    T val = temp.Pop();
    bool found = (val == minval || val == maxval);
    if (found && inPushMode)
        s.Push(val);
    if (found)
        inPushMode = !inPushMode;
    if (inPushMode)
        s.Push(val);

Здесь логика как-то уж совсем непрозрачна. Придумаете вариант поизящнее без индексов?

---
А что вы считаете в данном контексте честным и нечестным решением?

Comment: Ну одноэлементный стек не соответствует условиям задачи. Поведение для него должно оговариваться отдельно. "Нечестное" -- операции вне push/pop.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution [here](http://leetcode.com/2010/11/stack-that-supports-push-pop-and-getmin.html)

```
struct StackGetMin {
  void push(int x) {
    elements.push(x);
    if (minStack.empty() || x <= minStack.top())
      minStack.push(x);
  }
  bool pop() {
    if (elements.empty()) return false;
    if (elements.top() == minStack.top())
      minStack.pop();
    elements.pop();
    return true;
  }
  bool getMin(int &min) {
    if (minStack.empty()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      min = minStack.top();
      return true;
    }
  }
  stack<int> elements;
  stack<int> minStack;
};
```