# Работа со стеком №2

Tags: c++

Получив ответ на свой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/213012/c-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), я сел записывать решение. Но вот в этой части кода выскакивает ошибка: Value of type void is not allowed. Что неверно? Ошибка в 4 строке

```
stack <int> temp;
if (st1.empty())
    return;
int val = st1.pop();
int minidx = 0, maxidx = 0;
int minval = val, maxval = val;
temp.push(val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно возвращаться значение типа int: if (st1.empty()) return <- вот тут. Лучше вызвать исключение, т.к. код ошибки можно проигнорировать.

Comment: @Airhand, ничего не изменилось(  ....ошибка в этой строке: int val = st1.pop();

Comment: А как описана эта самая pop?

Comment: что значит как описана?...подключена библиотека stl

Comment: Тогда эта, как её...

      int val = st1.top();
      st1.pop();

Смотрите описание pop. Там чёрным по английскому говорят, 

     The value of this element can be retrieved before being popped by calling member stack::top.

(Значение этого элемента может быть получено перед выбрасыванием путём вызова члена stack::top

Comment: даааааааааааа.....

Comment: @alexlz, где описание посмотреть?)
здесь такая же ошибка:
while (!st1.empty())
{
    int val = st1.pop();
    if (val < minval)
    {
        minval = val;
        minidx = curridx;
    }
    if (val > maxval)
    {
        maxval = val;
        maxidx = curridx;
    }

В этой строке:  int val = st1.pop();

Comment: Я смотрю на www.cplusplus.com http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/ , но здесь он считается сайтом, содержащим немало ошибок. Надеюсь, спецы по C++ подскажут вариант получше.

Comment: ну, точно так же ведь:

    int val = st1.top();
    st1.pop();

В разных языках стек ведёт себя по-разному; в C++ `pop` _не_ возвращает "снятый" элемент, поэтому приходится "подглядывать" на вершину стека функцией `top`.

Comment: @alexlz: я обычно смотрю на [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/pop) (там, кстати, и чистыйC )